# Drag and Drop From HTML pages to C++ applications

Tags: javascript, c++, html, drag-and-drop, idataobject

I am trying to implement Drag And Drop Functionality from Web Pages to C++ Applications.

I am setting text on drag to dataTransfer object and now trying to access it on DropTarget from IDataObject. To Get Data from IDataObject, we need to specify FORMATETC, which I guess I am facing problem with.

Here is the code:
On HTML Side I have below javascript executed on Drag.

```
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
```

On C++ side:
I have DropTarget, implementing IDropTarget and inside ::Drop method i receive IDataObject.

To get data from this, I am using below code:

```
   FORMATETC fre;
   fre.cfFormat = CF_TEXT;
   fre.dwAspect = DVASPECT_CONTENT;
   fre.ptd = nullptr;
   fre.tymed = TYMED_HGLOBAL;
   fre.lindex = -1;

   STGMEDIUM stg;
   stg.hGlobal = nullptr;
   stg.pUnkForRelease = nullptr;

   bool result = false;

   if (NOERROR == pDataObj->GetData(&fre, &stg))
   {
       result = true;
   }
```

But I am not able to retrieve data here. Can someone please help me out here?

Thanks,
Kailas